# Performing chi-squared test of significance with zero (0) observed frequency in the contingency table

Tags: r, statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am trying to find if the `flag` is significantly affecting the `groups` distribution. I am trying to perform the `chi-squared test` but it is throwing a `NaN` value (as expected because 0 observed frequency for some groups). But then how to find if the 2 flags are really having 2 different distributions. Should I just remove the groups with 0 in either flag?

**Sample of the contingency table (contingency_table_wide)**

```
             groups
  flag    0-1    1-4    5-9  10-14  15-19  20-24  25-29  30-34 
     0      2      1      0  28798 218272 464149 519604 412537 
     1      0      0      0   4552  66845 157689 147428  99612
```

**Code**

```
contingency_table <- xtabs(~flag+groups, data=Result_table) 
    # xtabs is from stats package
contingency_table_wide <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(
    Freq ~ flag + groups, data=contingency_table)) 
    # for visual purposes
summary(contingency_table)
```

**Output**

```
Number of cases in table: 3173422 
Number of factors: 2 
Test for independence of all factors:
    Chisq = NaN, df = 18, p-value = NA
    Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Comment: Having some observed 0's isn't necessarily a problem in any way at all. The problem you're having occurs when you get an entire row or column of 0's. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131383/error-message-with-pearsons-chi-squared-test) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7429/computing-chi-square-for-large-tables-with-some-expected-cell-counts-equal-to-ze) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213761/how-to-proceed-with-chi-square-test-in-r-if-one-line-has-zeros)

Comment: @Glen_b I just realized that seeing one of your other answers. I used `drop.unused.levels = TRUE` in `xtabs()` and it removed the column `(5-9)` with all 0s. Will that give a valid chi-square statistic? Also, I am getting `p-value` as `0` after removal so that's no indication for something gone wrong?.

Comment: 1. Which answer did you see? 2. There's almost no information in the three low column categories because the column totals are so small. Note that combining the column of zeros with any other column is identical to dropping it, Unless it makes no sense to do so for your problem, I'd suggest combining the three leftmost columns. 3. With such huge counts you should expect extremely tiny p-values -- even very small effects will be detectable at huge sample sizes.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, I was referring to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115395/stats-for-2x4-contingency-table-with-both-very-large-and-small-or-zero-counts?rq=1) .
Thanks for explaining. If I may ask, does chi-square remain authentic here or I should do something else to see if the `flag` is casing a change in trend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there. Combining adjacent columns purely on the basic of the column totals (i.e. without reference to the pattern of values) should present no problem. If you're asking about whether - even after combining - the test statistic should be approximately distributed as chi-square in spite of two low expected values under the null (one a bit less than 1), that should be okay.

Comment: I have read somewhere that chi-square performs well when sample size around 100-2500 which is clearly not the case here. So should I rely on chi-square? Or should I divide all the frequencies to bring them down to that range? This was my doubt.

Comment: The issue of large sample sizes and hypothesis testing has been addressed many, many times on site. It's not unique to chi-square. [Making your hypothesis test inconsistent by throwing out most of the data any time the sample size gets large seems like a really bad idea -- that you would consider it suggests that you shouldn't be using hypothesis tests at all. What are you really trying to find out?]

Comment: When you say causing a change in trend do you mean a linear trend for your groups variable?

Comment: @Glen_b @mdewey What I really want to find is if the `flag = 1` affected the distribution for groups and if the distribution is different than that when `flag = 0`  (sorry for the delayed reply)

Answer (score 2):

There is much advice in the comments. @Glen_b's advice to collapse the first three rows gives

```r
chisq.test(collapsed_table[, 2:3], sim=TRUE)

Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000
    replicates)

data:  collapsed_table[, 2:3]
X-squared = 7358.8, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

But I will look into another idea. Your column names indicates that you have grouped (binned) a continuous variable, it might have been better to avoid that if possible. So I introduce a variable `x` by using the interval midpoints as values, and the use the R package `mgcv`to fit a binomial (logistic) smooth regression. Smoothing then is a way to solve the problem of low counts. This gives

```r
mod0 <- mgcv::gam( cbind(flag0, flag1) ~ s(x, k=3),  
            data=as.data.frame(mydata), family=binomial)
summary(mod0)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
cbind(flag0, flag1) ~ s(x, k = 3)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.90805    0.01306   146.1   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
     edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x)   2      2   6718  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.886   Deviance explained = 91.4%
UBRE = 80.934  Scale est. = 1         n = 8
```

and the following plot:

[image: Fit smooth (by a spline) of variable x]

In this case a simple generalized linear model (R function `glm` with a quadratic term for `x` would have given a very similar result.

R code to read the data and make tables used above:

```r
data_text <- "NA       0.5     2.5    7   12     17     22     27     32
             0      2      1      0  28798 218272 464149 519604 412537 
             1      0      0      0   4552  66845 157689 147428  99612 "

 mydata <- matrix(scan(textConnection(data_text), sep=""), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE) 
 mydata <- t(mydata)
 mydata <- mydata[-1, ]
 colnames(mydata) <- c("x", "flag0", "flag1")
 dimnames(mydata)[[1]] <- as.character(mydata[, 1])

collapsed_table <- mydata[-(1:3), ]
 collapsed_table <- rbind(mydata[1, ] + mydata[2, ] + mydata[3, ], 
 collapsed_table)
```

Comment: Much simpler:  `X <- matrix(c(0 ,     2 ,     1  ,    0 , 28798, 218272, 464149, 519604, 412537, 
              1 ,     0 ,     0 ,     0 ,  4552 , 66845, 157689, 147428 , 99612 ), 9);
Y <- X[rowSums(X) > 0, ];
chisq.test(Y, simulate.p.value = TRUE)`